# GitHub の利用を便利にする通知系ツールについて

Tags: github

皆さんが GitHub を使いやすくするために入れているツールはありますか？
コマンドライン, ブラウザ拡張, Windows や Mac のアプリなど, いろいろあると思います.
特に通知系ツールが知りたいです！

Comment: 良い質問だと思いますが、英語のstackoverflowだったらcloseされそうですね。なぜなら、回答を客観的に決められないからか回答が一つでないからである。まして時間が経つとともに回答が変わりそうだと思われます。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows

Comment: "git"だけでは十分じゃない?

Comment: nacho4d さん, コメントありがとうございます. 本家 Stack Overflow のローカルルールについてあまり詳しくないのに質問してしまいました. すみません.

Comment: 質問の方向を変えた方が役に立つ質問になると、個人的に思います。「GitHubからの通知をMacの通知センターで受け取れるようにしたいのですが」など、具体的に絞る感じです。それはそれとして、ローカルルールは日本語版で独自に作っていいものなので、投票の様子を見た方がいいかなと思います。メタに[英語版での扱いをまとめたもの](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/30)があるので、参考になれば。

Comment: mattn さんの編集リクエストを承認し, 質問タイトルを変更いたしました. 一覧系質問については色々議論をしてきた歴史があったのですね. 勉強になりました. ありがとうございます.

Comment: 質問タイトルを変更して頂いた結果、具体的な回答がしやすくなったと思いますので、質問を再オープンしました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHubの自分のタイムラインを通知センターで通知してくれるMacの常駐型アプリの[PopHub](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/pophub/id928494006?mt=12)が便利です。

Answer (score 3):

ioctocatとSlackに落ち着きました。

- https://ioctocat.com/
- https://slack.com/

Answer (score 3):

通知のみで言えば、 [Trailer](https://github.com/ptsochantaris/trailer) というものがありますね。
Mac,iOS,Android のみですがそれなりに優秀です。

Answer (score 2):

Kanban が好きであれば [ZenHub](https://www.zenhub.io/) はオススメです。Issue/PR の一覧は数が多くなってくると俯瞰しにくいです。

Comment: ZenHubについてまとめたQiitaの記事です。 http://qiita.com/GeckoTang/items/f75b9a1c20c8e5091147 大体の機能について触れていると思います。

Answer (score 1):

通知系ではないですが、hubでしょうか

https://hub.github.com

Comment: hubがどういうものかの説明もあると回答として分かりやすいです。回答は後から[edit]できます。質問自体につっこみが入ってますが、なるべく役に立つQ&Aに育ててみるのもよいと思います。

Comment: いつの間にか内容が少し変わってしまい、その内容にそぐわなくなった理由で、マイナスモデのようなので、編集する意味が無いようですね。

Comment: そうですね。もうちょっと様子を見た方がよかったかと反省してます。なお、回答は削除することでマイナスを帳消しにできます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ですが、折角の
日本語版初めての回答なので、残しておこうと思います。

Answer (score 1):

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)は通知系ツールです。

かなり使いやすいです。私のプロジェクトでデベロッパー、デザイナーさん、翻訳者はみんなSoureTreeを使っています。オススメです。